# How to put int type variable into dynamic

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I  tried to design a dynamic SQL script.
however, I forgot  how to pass int type variable(@t) into the script.
Instead of using convert function to change data type to varchar, I remember I can just use some ' or " then I can pass them into my varchar variable(@script) then execute later. Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks!!

The following are my codes

```
create table #test
(
    id int
    ,name nvarchar(20)
)
insert into #test (id, name) values (1, 'ggg'),(2, 'hhh'),(3, 'ppp')
select * from #test
declare @t as int
declare @script as nvarchar(200)
set @t = 2
set @script = 'select * from #test ' 
set @script = @script + 'where id =' + @t
exec(@script)
```

Comment: If your sql server version 2012 or higher you can use CONCAT.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  That will automatically handled any datatype conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can you [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to convert int to nvarchar :

..

```
set @script = @script + 'where id =' + CAST(@t as nvarchar(max))
```

..

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches:

```
create table #test(id int,name nvarchar(20));
insert into #test (id, name) values (1, 'ggg'),(2, 'hhh'),(3, 'ppp')

declare @t int=2;
declare @script nvarchar(200);
```

--cast to varchar

```
set @script='select * from #test where id =' + CAST(@t AS VARCHAR(100));
```

--convert for the same effect

```
set @script ='select * from #test where id =' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@t);
```

--Use `CONCAT` (needs SQL-Server 2012+)

```
set @script =CONCAT('select * from #test where id =',@t);

exec(@script);
```

But this is what you really should do:

```
set @script ='select * from #test where id = @id';

EXEC sp_executesql @script,N'@id INT',@id=@t;
```

Concatenating statements (and especially parameters!) dynamically, opens you for [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If you use values coming from user input you might meet [little bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).